# Microsoft.Data.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found

Tags: azure, devops

Wanting to build a Pipeline to generate a dacpac from a database solution. But the build fails with this error message

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamData\Microsoft.Data.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found.

Running this on a self hosted agent, I installed SSDT tools along with VS2017 but the file that was added was "Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets"  <-- note the "Tools" ; so basically the build still fails.

Will appreciate guidance. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Update : I checked the project file and it is set to look for "Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" which makes it weird why the build server is looking for a different file in a different path